# Can I toggle Do Not Disturb on/off on my Mac as easily as I can on my iPhone?

Tags: macos, shortcut, notifications, do-not-disturb

On my iPhone I can use the Control Center to toggle Do Not Disturb on and off whenever I want.

On my Mac I checked in System Preferences > Notifications and I can set it on a schedule, but there’s no option to show a Do Not Disturb icon in the Menu Bar.

How can I easily toggle Do Not Disturb on/off on my Mac without going into System Preferences or having to use Terminal?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Option + Click the menu bar**

Actually, there is a Menu Bar icon, of sorts.

To toggle Do Not Disturb you can just hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down while you click on the Notification Centre icon at top right of your Menu Bar.

Doing this will instantly make any visible notifications disappear and grey out the icon. You can still click on it to manually show/hide the Notification Centre whenever you want, but Do Not Disturb stays active.

**NOTE:** Do Not Disturb will stay active until the next day (when it becomes inactive again) or until you once again hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while clicking on the Notification Centre icon.

**Keyboard shortcut**

You can also create a keyboard shortcut. To do this:

1. Go to **Apple > System Preferences...**
2. Select the **Keyboard** preference pane
3. Select the **Shortcuts** tab
4. In the left-hand pane select **Mission Control**
5. On the right-hand side tick the **Turn Do Not Disturb On/Off** checkbox
6. Now press the keys you want to use for your shortcut (e.g. in the screenshot below I've chosen <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)

[image]

7. Exit System Preferences

Now you should be able to use that Keyboard shortcut to toggle Do Not Disturb on/off as required.

**NOTE:** If a keyboard shortcut you've set up doesn't work, then it's most likely already in use for another purpose within macOS. Likewise, if it doesn't work while you're in a particular app, then it may conflict with an app-specific shortcut. In either case you will need to change your shortcut.

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: I never knew about the OPTION-click capability. Drop-down and slide-in yes, but OPTION-click, no. Nice.

Comment: I successfully added a keyboard shortcut, but the first one I tried didn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: @TorBro Thanks for the question/feedback. :) The shortcut must have already been in use. I've added a note to the end of my answer to clarify.

Comment: Please see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371909/can-i-make-do-not-disturb-on-my-mac-active-24-7-and-still-check-notifications-ma

Answer (score 25):

Complementing Monomeeth's excellent answer, there's also a toggle button available in the Notification Center in macOS. This is sort of the shortcut (albeit a bit lengthy) you are looking for.

Click on the Notification Center button in the far right on the Menu bar to reveal the Notification Center UI.

[image]

Now with the Today tab selected, scroll down to reveal the Do Not Disturb toggle.

[image]

---

Additionally, if you have *Hey Siri* enabled, you can simply ask Siri to toggle *Do Not Disturb*.

[image]

Comment: Great info, but I imagine that talking out loud to your computer to put it in DND mode isn't something that gets a lot of use!

Comment: "scroll down to reveal the Do Not Disturb toggle": I would describe it as scrolling up (by dragging/swiping down), though [it is ambiguous](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/whichway.html)! :)

Answer (score 15):

As well as the answers given, if your Mac has a Touch Bar, you can customise it to include a toggle for Do Not Disturb in the Control Strip which is (nearly) always visible. Of course, you'll have to give up one of the other functions from the Control Strip -- the defaults are brightness, volume, mute and Siri.

[image: Screenshot of Touch Bar customization pane with the Do Not Disturb option hand circled in red.]

Comment: After using this toggle, I get the menu bar icon, but as soon as I disable it, it will be gone. It would be nice to always have the menu bar icon.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a trackpad, and you want to enter "Do Not Disturb" mode with gestures, then go to System Preferences->Trackpad->More Gestures and turn on "Notification Centre".

[image: Trackpad panel in System Preferences]

Now you can swipe to the left with two fingers from the edge of the trackpad to open the Notification Center. Now swipe down with two fingers to reveal the Do Not Disturb switch.

[image: Do Not Disturb switch in Notification Center]

If you like gestures, then this is the way to go!